# Can't finalise python set-ups - Subprocesses file causing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, subprocess

Firstly, I'd just like to say my level of python programming is absolute beginner so please be patient!

I've installed Python 3.7.4, along with some packages such as numpy, xlwings and (most importantly) selenium.
I've downloaded the this onto my 64-bit windows 10 laptop and followed the [advice of the Python forum](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Part-1-Python-3-6-3-7-and-pip-installation-under-Windows) to address issues particular to Windows but still, when I try to run a *slightly* modified version of [this example code](https://github.com/jg-fisher/autoFB/blob/master/fbtest.py) which basically opens a browser (the sample opens firefox, I'm using Chrome - they both have this same issue!), navigates to facebook and logs-in.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

username = 'fb_email@email.com'
password = 'fb_password'

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\webdriver.py")

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
```

When I run this code I'm getting the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:/Python37/Codes/Test.py", line 9, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py")
>   File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)   File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

You'll notice one other change I've made from the original code is I've include the full file path (explicitly referencing `Webdrive.py` file) to deal with the "permissions" error.

Basically, I just want to get to the stage I can run this code and I can do I know I can run selenium on python in principal and deal with the nested looping within the python code at a later date so any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\webdriver.py")` is the line which is having issue because, you have to pass the path of chromedriver.exe as executable_path not the `.py` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root Cause:**
You are not providing the correct path to the `executable_path` in line # 9. <kbd>executable_path</kbd> should point to the <kbd>chromedriver.exe</kbd> path not the `p.py` path.

**How to fix:**

Update the line#9 with the correct path to the chromedriver.exe.

```
# make sure you add `.exe` file name too at the end like `chromedriver.exe`.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"pathToChromedriver")
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm at work at the moment but will look into this when I get home!